# SP or query to dump "password policy" checkbox for all logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

`sp_helplogins` doesn't show a column for this. I need a listing of all logins, with the status of their "Enforce password policy" checkbox. This is for an auditor, and the standard practice is for screenshots of every login. I'd prefer to make this simpler on me (to generate) and simpler on them to audit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the start of a report:

```
SELECT
    sp.name AS LoginName,
    sl.is_policy_checked AS IsPasswordPolicyEnforced
    FROM sys.server_principals sp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_logins sl ON sl.principal_id = sp.principal_id
    WHERE sp.type IN ('S', 'G', 'U');
```

Note that this property only applies to SQL logins.

Answer (score 0):

Hmph. Found it :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244387/help-needed-to-write-sql-query-for-sql-logins

`SELECT name, is_policy_checked  FROM sys.sql_logins`